# Excel function that copies 2 rows of data and then skips n rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBjdL.jpg

basically what I want to do is only copy the cells that are in orange and ignore the rest.

forgetting the top label, I want to skip 10 rows -> copy the next 2 rows -> skip 10 rows -> copy the next 2 rows. rinse and repeat. I tried =OFFSET and =INDEX but I'm not getting anywhere with it. any ideas?

Comment: have you considered using auto-filter and then a filter by color? Once you get a filtered list, you could easily copy the multiple blocks of cells and paste it into a separate contiguous location. Or is it necessary for you to do it using formulaes/code? note: Filter by color may not be available in older versions prior to Excel 2007

Comment: in the actual dataset there are like 10,000+ rows, so I would have to manually add colors to the cells I actually want. I prefer to use formulas to select the cells i need. I want to "clean" the data so that I only see the "orange" cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely must do it using formula, here's one you can try:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),ROW()*6,(ROW()-1)*6+1)-1,0)
```

Paste this in cell B2 and copy it down.

The first cell in a set of cells you want to copy happens to be a multiple of 12, and the second one is the subsequent cell.

I've offset that number (depending on whether the row number is even or not) from cell A1, which is why 1 is subtracted from the second argument of `OFFSET` function.

The `IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),ROW()*6,(ROW()-1)*6+1)` part returns a multiple of 12 if the cell you're entering it in is on an even row, or the number next to that multiple if it's on an odd row.